# "For" v. "to" with "respect", "deference"

Tags: prepositions

What is the rule? Is it simply "use 'for' with 'respect', use 'to' with 'deference'", as the sentence below suggests, or is it more complicated than that?

> She covered her head out of/in deference **to** (= because of a polite respect **for**) Muslim custom.

*(from the [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/ru/%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C/%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9/deference?q=Deference%20))*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idiomatic standard here is [***in deference to...***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=out%20of%20deference%20to%2Cout%20of%20deference%20for%2Cin%20deference%20to%2Cin%20deference%20for&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cout%20of%20deference%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cout%20of%20deference%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20deference%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20deference%20for%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cout%20of%20deference%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cout%20of%20deference%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20deference%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20deference%20for%3B%2Cc0)

[image]

It's less common to use ***out of*** instead of ***in*** for the initial element, but no-one would think it was particularly "unusual". Except that looking at it now I see that in this exact context, the apparent opposites ***out** [of]* and ***in*** are completely equivalent and interchangeable, which seems a little odd!

I won't bother to *display* the corresponding chart for [***out of respect for***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in%20respect%20for%2Cin%20respect%20to%2Cout%20of%20respect%20for%2Cout%20of%20respect%20to&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20respect%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20respect%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cout%20of%20respect%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cout%20of%20respect%20to%3B%2Cc0), but if you follow the link you'll see this is the *only* acceptable version of the four permutations of prepositions with ***respect***.